# Realloc allocates more memory than requested

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have a problem with below function.

When I try to `realloc()` memory I get more than I actually asked for!

In this instance I try to concatenate 2 strings, one who is 14 characters long and one who is 11 characters long, but the end result is that `memTemp` is 38 characters long even though `memNewSize` shows that it is in fact 25, does anyone know what to do?

```
int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source)
{
    assert(destination != NULL); // Precondition: destination ar ej NULL
    assert(*destination != NULL); // Precondition: *destination ar ej NULL
    assert(source != NULL); // Precondition: source ar ej NULL
    //Dstring looks like this = "typedef char* Dstring;"

    int memNewSize = strlen(*destination) + strlen(source);
    char *memTemp;
    memTemp = (char*)realloc(memTemp, sizeof(char) * memNewSize);

    printf("%d\n", memNewSize);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(memTemp));

    if(memTemp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate new memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *destination = memTemp;
        strcat(*destination, source);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course the title should've been "realloc allocates too much memory"

Comment: Then why not edit it?

Comment: what is `DString`?

Comment: Should it not be `memNewSize + 1` to include the string terminator?

Comment: As for your problem, would it not make more sense to pass `*destination` to the `realloc` call?

Comment: Are you hiding pointer with typedef `DString` ? it's **very very** bad idea. By the way, your question is lack of [mcve], I vote to close.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to `realloc` be the old pointer?

Comment: @Erik.E - I think the suggestion regarding the title pertains to somewhat of a title misconception. E.g "`realloc` is doing something wrong." Or, "some `C-library function` is doing something wrong..." 99.999% of the time, it is not the library function that is at fault.

Comment: How do you know that "`memTemp` is 38 characters long"?  Seems to me that you are attempting an `strlen` on uninitialised memory.  `strlen` will just run along looking for a binary zero`.  Eventually it will either find one or run into an illegal address, either way the reported length will be wrong.

Comment: No, realloc doesn't allocate "more memory than requested". Ignoring all the other bugs that have been pointed out, there are no standard methods for you to find out how much memory realloc gave you. Calling strlen on uninitialized memory is definitely not the way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is, `realloc()` works (*properly*) on only

- pointers earlier returned by allocator function
- `NULL` pointers.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified `size`. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. [....]

In your case, `memTemp` (being an automatic storage local scoped variable) is just an unitialized pointer, with an *indeterminate value*, pointing to *who knows what* address! It's not even guaranteed to be `NULL`. So, all you have is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Just a guess: Probably you meant to initialize `memTemp` with incoming `*destination`?*

---

That said, as pointed out in comments under the actual question,

- The size multiplier supplied in `realloc()` should be `memNewSize + 1` to be able to hold the null-terminator.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` in C, so using it as a multiplier is redundant.

Comment: Do you have a user script to one-click-quote a section from the standard :p

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya :) Not really, it's just a bad habit I developed myself to avoid misunderstanding by using wrong wordings (English is not my native language and believe me, I had been in situations where what I wrote was 180 degrees what what I meant!!)

Comment: Hey there Sourav, thanks for the fast answer! Dstring is a typedef that is a char pointer, so Dstring *destination is actually a char double pointer, and *destination points already to an dynamically allocated string, so should memTemp be a problem if I use *destination in my realloc() call?

Comment: @Erik.E it is generally a good idea not to hide pointers in typedefs

Comment: @Erik.E No, there should not be any problem if I understood your version correctly.

Comment: ..and I second what @AjayBrahmakshatriya said, it's really a _bad_ thing.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Sorry, I got this code from my teacher, my job was to implement the different functions that comes with it :/

Comment: @SouravGhosh So what could be the problem then? If newMemSize is 25, and *destination points to an already allocated string, Why does memTemp end up being 38 characters big?

Comment: @Erik.E it should not be. Point: `*destination points to an already allocated string`..it must be returned via allocator functions, otherwise, we're back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it to work, thanks so much guys! Updated code below.

```
int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source)
{
    assert(destination != NULL); // Precondition: destination ar ej NULL
    assert(*destination != NULL); // Precondition: *destination ar ej NULL
    assert(source != NULL); // Precondition: source ar ej NULL
    // Dstring look like this = "typedef char* Dstring;"

    int memNewSize = strlen(*destination) + strlen(source);
    char *memTemp;
    memTemp = (char*)realloc(*destination, sizeof(char) * memNewSize+1);

    if(memTemp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate new memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *destination = memTemp;
        strcat(*destination, source);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `memTemp = realloc (*destination, sizeof *memTemp * memNewSize+1);`? See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)